# Decode excel date mask

Tags: excel, vba, decode, date

I need to try to find an algorithm to decode a set of Excel dates.

A former employee once told me he could encode a date in Excel and no one would ever figure it out,  he said "like a needle in a haystack".   My response was "Why would someone want to do that?"  After his departure with the theft of a large amount of data, I find a set of charts with "record numbers" labeled  anywhere from from T20000 to T39999.  These charts should have accompanying birthdates, but do not - the birthdates are missing.  These charts were hidden in our usual charts which are 6 to 7 digits and pure numeric only rather than starting with a "T".  Given this background(and other data), I doubt this was done for innocent reasons and suspect fraud, such as Medicare or insurance fraud.  **The 5 digits after the "T" could encode the birthdates.**  These are similar to the usual 5 digit numbers Excel uses to store dates.  I was able to find some birthdates by finding other ways to look them up.  A few examples are:

```
Record #         Exel DOB   (real) DOB
T30007            27369     12/6/1974
T31414            16803     1/1/1946
T31738            22156     8/28/1960
```

There are 2-3 K of these without birthdates.

Simple addition or subtraction does not find the answer.  I suspect he added(or subtracted) then flipped the individual digits, then added(or subtracted) again or a similar algorithm. Changing the order of the 5 digits like 5 cards in poker(The former employee played a lot of poker).

I wrote an Excel VBA program to try to evaluate this using trials of: 1) adding 1 to 9999, 2) then switching the order of the last 4 digits, then 3) adding or subtracting 1 to 9999. However, the number of possibilities (9999 * 2^4 * 9999 * 2 ) far exceeds the row limits in Excel(with non matches excluded) and breaking it into smaller parts still ran too slowly on my non gaming computers.   I am not well versed in C, Java or Python, but suspect these may be better options.

My slow running Excel VBA code:

```
Sub Decode_DOB()
'The accompanying table is Sheet1 which this runs off


Dim Org(111, 5) As Long
Dim BD1(111, 5) As Long
Dim Var_1(111, 5) As Long
Dim VarTT(111) As Long
Dim VarTT1(111) As Long
Dim VarTT2(111) As Long
Dim Save_Counter As Long
Dim icounter As Long
Dim int_Digit_Count As Integer


Save_Counter = 1 'Counter to save the spreadsheet at intervals
 

icounter = 2  'Counter to keep track of current row number


'Org(x,y) array to store the original chart record starting with "T"
'Org(n2,0) for the total 5 digit number, then Org(n2,1 to 5) to break out each digit

For n2 = 2 To 25
Org(n2, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(n2, 2).Value
Org(n2, 1) = Mid(Org(n2, 0), 1, 1)
Org(n2, 2) = Mid(Org(n2, 0), 2, 1)
Org(n2, 3) = Mid(Org(n2, 0), 3, 1)
Org(n2, 4) = Mid(Org(n2, 0), 4, 1)
Org(n2, 5) = Mid(Org(n2, 0), 5, 1)
Next n2

'BD1(x,y) array to store the original chart record starting with "T"
'BD1(n1,0) for the total 5 digit number, then BD1(n1,1 to 5) to break out each digit

For n1 = 2 To 25
BD1(n1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(n1, 28).Value
BD1(n1, 1) = Mid(BD1(n1, 0), 1, 1)
BD1(n1, 2) = Mid(BD1(n1, 0), 2, 1)
BD1(n1, 3) = Mid(BD1(n1, 0), 3, 1)
BD1(n1, 4) = Mid(BD1(n1, 0), 4, 1)
BD1(n1, 5) = Mid(BD1(n1, 0), 5, 1)
Next n1


'Sequentially try adding 1 to 9999

For n = 1 To 9999
For i = 2 To 25
Var_1(i, 0) = Org(i, 0) - n
Var_1(i, 1) = Mid(Var_1(i, 0), 1, 1)
Var_1(i, 2) = Mid(Var_1(i, 0), 2, 1)
Var_1(i, 3) = Mid(Var_1(i, 0), 3, 1)
Var_1(i, 4) = Mid(Var_1(i, 0), 4, 1)
Var_1(i, 5) = Mid(Var_1(i, 0), 5, 1)

'Sequentially "Flip the digits" or "Cards" only using the last 4
For k = 2 To 5
For l = 2 To 5
For m = 2 To 5
For p = 2 To 5
'Combine digits to get the total 5 digit number
VarTT(i) = Var_1(i, 1) * 10000 + Var_1(i, k) * 1000 + Var_1(i, l) * 100 + Var_1(i, m) * 10 + Var_1(i, p)

'Sequentially  and and subtract from the result
For ii = 1 To 9999
VarTT1(i) = VarTT(i) + ii
VarTT2(i) = VarTT(i) - ii

    'Test valid "Flips" - only one of each digit allowed
    'and the total 1+2+3+4+5 should = 15
    
    int_Digit_Count = 1 + k + l + m + p
    If (k = l Or k = m) Or k = p Then
    int_Digit_Count = 0
    End If
    
    If l = m Or l = p Then
    int_Digit_Count = 0
    End If
    
    If m = p Then
    int_Digit_Count = 0
    End If
    
    
    'test to see if the result matches the birthdate
    If VarTT1(i) = BD1(i, 0) Or VarTT2(i) = BD1(i, 0) Then
    'and test for valid "Flip"
    If int_Digit_Count = 15 Then
    
    'If the sequence and valid flip creates a match, write to Sheet2
           
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 1).Value = i
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 2).Value = Org(i, 0)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 3).Value = Org(i, 0) - n
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 4).Value = VarTT(i)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 5).Value = BD1(i, 0)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 6).Value = n
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 7).Value = Var_1(i, 1)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 8).Value = Var_1(i, 2)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 9).Value = Var_1(i, 3)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 10).Value = Var_1(i, 4)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 11).Value = Var_1(i, 5)
        
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 13).Value = 1
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 14).Value = k
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 15).Value = l
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 16).Value = m
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 17).Value = p
        
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 19).Value = VarTT1(i)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 20).Value = VarTT2(i)
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 21).Value = ii
        
        FlipPattern = 1 * 10000 + k * 1000 + l * 100 + m * 10 + p
        
        Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 22).Value = FlipPattern
              
                      
        
        icounter = icounter + 1
        
        'Save the spreadsheet every 5000 rows in case the program "blows up"
        Save_Counter = Save_Counter + 1
        
            If Save_Counter > 5000 Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Save
                Save_Counter = 1
                Sheet2.Cells(1, 12).Value = icounter
                Sheet2.Cells(icounter, 24).Value = Time()
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            End If
    
            
    End If
    End If
    
'ii for last number added or subtracted
    Next ii

'p,m,l,k for flip sequences
Next p
Next m
Next l
Next k

'For each "T" number on Sheet 1
Next i

Next n
'Matches can then be sorted on n, "Flip" and ii and look for a "common denominator"
End Sub



Sub Sort_Matches()
'Run this after sorting to mark multiple matches and filter
last_row = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For ijj = 2 To last_row

If Sheet5.Cells(ijj, 6).Value = Sheet5.Cells(ijj - 1, 6).Value Then
If Sheet5.Cells(ijj, 21).Value = Sheet5.Cells(ijj - 1, 21).Value Then
If Sheet5.Cells(ijj, 22).Value = Sheet5.Cells(ijj - 1, 22).Value Then

Sheet5.Cells(ijj - 1, 23).Value = "XX"
Sheet5.Cells(ijj, 23).Value = "XX"

End If
End If
End If

Next ijj


End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "charts", are you talking about Excel charts, like line chart, bar chart, pie charts? I cannot see how one could hide a chart in a chart.

Comment: Porobably better on the Code Golf or Cryptography Stacks.

Comment: Do you have any data that is 100% correct (a few records only)? If so, could you post it as text?

Comment: "patient charts" -- talk about confusing use of terminology. How were we supposed to know that?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide further details. Do NOT put clarification into comments, because nobody wants to read through a wall of comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Please, try posting only three encrypted cases versus how they must look. Otherwise, it would be impossible to imagine a decryption algorithm, not knowing what to be obtained...

Comment: There is a practically infinite number of ways to encode dates as 5-digit numbers. If his programming skills matches his lack of ethics, your task might be infeasible. On the other hand, people are often not as clever as they think that they are in writing custom encryption algorithms. I agree with @SolarMike that Stack Overflow might not be the best stack exchange community to ask this on.

Comment: Since there are more than 1 person born in a single day, it seems unlikely that the number which follows the T is an encryption of the date (though it perhaps contains that information). When you are dealing with thousands of records, using (encrypted) birth dates as record identifiers in not very useful. Why do you think that this is what they did?

Comment: He was trying to hide something, I suspect some type of fraud.  He was not any type of programmer, but could have had someone help him.  His main interest in numbers was through poker.  There may be a code in the account's name for if there were duplicate dates such as a middle initial..  Most do not have middle initials.

Comment: Your question is probably impossible to answer, given just the information that you have provided. We can't guess the thought processes of some unknown person with some unknown (though probably nefarious) motives in some unknown context. If this is at all important to your company, perhaps you could hire some computer security/forensics consultant and give them the access that they would need to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Thanks y'all!  Unfortunately, the "bad guy" stole the old LAN server along with other (likely incriminating) data when he left.  I am able to see record/chart numbers and some demographics on a proprietary service online, but this does not let me copy and paste so I have to copy all data manually.

Comment: Those that start with a "T" only have the record "number",  name and phone numbers.   In looking for duplicate "birth dates" from the above comment by John, I was able to find someone else I personally know in the files.  Conversation with her gave further evidence of my suspicions of potential billing fraud.  If would be helpful to know the birthdates to better associate people with other records, but I may go to Medicare without it.  They may have an easier way to figure it out or maybe not even need it.